# I can't find a conenction diagarm for the OV7670 camera to the ESP8266

Tags: configuration, camera, android-camera, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I cannot find  any connection diagram from NODEMCU ESP8266 TO THE OV7670 CAMERA MODULE. What pin in the board should be connected to the pin in the camera. There are 20 pins.